# Avoid framework lock-in with dependency inversion

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-inversion

I am trying to understand the concept of dependency inversion and I think I finally got the concept. However now I am struggling with another issue, which is the selection of framework, when implementing it in .NET, at least.

Say I have a business logic assembly which has the need for a data access class. For that I add an interface for the data model and data access class in the business logic assembly (as shown in the drawing below). The actual implementation of the data access interface(s) is done in a different assembly (project).

This ensures that my business logic does not need to know anything about the implementation of the data access. However, it also means that if my business logic is implemented in .NET Core, then my data access assembly needs to be implemented in .NET Core as well.

Isn't there any way to avoid this, so I don't couple the framework of my data access assembly to that of my business logic application?

In other words, can I get the left part of my drawing to be in .NET Core and the right part to be in .NET Standard (for instance)?

[image: Dependency inversion illustrated]

Comment: You can have all project to be .net standard. Only one entry point application, where main method exists can be .net core

Comment: @Fabio that's true. But is that I normal way of doing it? I would think that there would be stuff in .NET Core (or Framework) which you would like access to, in your core program?

Comment: yes. use standard for everything possible as it has the greatest compatibility

Comment: Your library shouldn’t have knowledge about data access. Don’t put that IDataAccess in your business domain. Instead make the client of the library depend on both, so it can instantiate domain objects with data.

Comment: You should study differences between .NET Standard, Framework and Core . Most of your problems seem to stem from not understanding their purpose and how they interact.

Comment: I know it’s asking a lot, but could anyone illustrate in an answer, what to put where, and which assemblies that should depend on each other? There seems to be a lot of good stuff in the comments. It would be awesome to see it boiled into a complete answer 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I think you are confused about terminology. Two possible compilation targets are ".NET Framework" (owned by Microsoft and developed for Windows) and ".NET Core" (which is open source and cross-platform).  ".NET Standard" isn't really a compilation target-- there is no such thing as an assembly "compiled in .NET standard." It is [a specification](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) to which a framework can comply. When a framework is compliant to .NET Standard, that means it supports a core set of functions that Microsoft has defined as essential.

Now to address your question. No, you cannot combine .NET Core and .NET Framework in a single process space, so the idea of injecting a dependency from an assembly compiled against a different framework is simply not possible (and if it were, it'd be really confusing).

The way this sort of problem is solved is via *recompilation*. You compile the code under the framework you need, and if you want to switch frameworks, you recompile. Since different frameworks support different things, you may have to modify some of your code for recompilation to succeed. But if all of your code sticks to .NET Standard, that shouldn't be an issue-- that is exactly why it was invented.

Comment: So basically you create an assembly as .NET Standard (assuming of course, that you think it will provide you some benefit) and then you compile it as .NET Core/Framework, when you need it?

Comment: Yes I think you have the idea.

Comment: I don’t this this answer is completely correct. In some cases, you can actually call .net framework libs from .net core. See: https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/606

Comment: This isn't exactly correct answer. .NET Standard is a compilation target. It means that the DLL produced has format and uses APIs that then can be executed by .NET Core or .NET Framework.

Comment: `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` disagrees with your first paragraph. Why shouldn't a specification be a valid compilation target?

Answer (score 1):

You can mix and match, but you may get a lit of runtime DLLs added to older .net projects. See here for examples

https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ReferencingNETStandardAssembliesFromBothNETCoreAndNETFramework.aspx
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2019/Feb/19/Using-NET-Standard-with-Full-Framework-NET